# Include muparser library into QtCreator

Tags: qt-creator

I need to import muparser library into QtCreator. I build them with MinGW as static library and as a result i get libmuparser.a file.
The library is located in C:\muparser\muparser_v2_2_3.
This is my .pro file:

```
QT       += core    
QT       -= gui    
INCLUDEPATH += C:\muparser\muparser_v2_2_3\include
LIBS        += -LC:\muparser\muparser_v2_2_3\lib

TARGET = muparsertest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app    

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

This is my main:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "muParser.h"

using namespace mu;    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Parser p;

    return a.exec();
}
```

The inclusion works, because with an empty main i don't get any error, but when i try to create a muparser object like in the posted main, i get these errors:

```
error: undefined reference to `mu::Parser::Parser()'
error: undefined reference to `vtable for mu::Parser' 
error: undefined reference to `mu::ParserBase::~ParserBase()'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a competent answer, but some sources suggest adding the muparser library directory to DEPENDPATH (see: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/20258-Qt-and-muParser)
My experience is:  muparser.dll generally reproduces this kind of problem.  Build again disabling the "dynamic" option in the muparser Makefile and simply add
LIBS += /libmuparser.a
in your .pro file.